# How to return the value from main function when error happens in sub function

Tags: php

I need to return the value from main function named excute();

```
class twCrawlerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    public function test(){
        $some.... // error happnes!!
            return '1'//errorcode '1';
    }

    public function excute(){
        $returncode = $this->test();
        if ($returncode){return $returncode;}

    }

}
```

In this code, I can return the $returncode when error happnes in test();

However, what if the function nest is more deeper or complicated?

I think it might be a bit clumsy to pass the $returncode one-by-one.

Is there any better way to pass the returncode to main function?

Comment: What kind of error? can't you use Exception Handling for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class twCrawlerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand {
    private errCode = 0;
    private function test() {
        $some.... // error happens!!
        $this->errCode = 1;
    }
    public function excute() {
        $this->test();
        if($this->errCode !== 0) {
            return $this->errCode;
            $this->errCode = 0; //reset
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks,I got many good anser,what important is to keep error information in class member.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, your best choice may be [exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). One of their intentions is quite what you want. For example:

```
function foo($x)
{
   if($x)
   {
      throw new Exception($x);
   }
   return 0;
}

function bar($y)
{
   try
   {
      foo($y);
      //some other logic here. Useful part of function
      //should be placed here
      return 'well done';
   }
   catch(Exception $e)
   {
      //for example, in case that you'll want to get not just code
      return $e->getMessage();
   }
}

echo bar(-1);//-1
echo bar(0);//well done
```

-you can control your execution with error handling and put your logic into `try` part, handling different errors in `catch` part. Note, that you can catch many different exceptions - so it may be more than one `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Then your code would look like this

```
class twCrawlerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    public function test(){
        throw new \RuntimeException('Something wrong happened here');
    }

    public function excute(){
        try {
            $this->test();
        } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
            // handle exception with message in $e->getMessage()
        }
   }

}
```

Comment: You need to use `finally` clause to return the value.

Comment: Not really, as `finally` is available as of `PHP 5.5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a property

```
class twCrawlerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
   public $last_error = false;

    public function test(){
        $some.... // error happnes!! 
            $this->last_error = "error description";
            return '1'//errorcode '1';
    }

    public function excute(){
        $returncode = $this->test();
        if ($returncode){return $returncode;}

    }

}
```

...
somewhere outside the class:

```
if ($twCrawlerCommandInstance->execute() !== "0")
  echo("something bad happened: ".$twCrawlerCommandInstance->last_error);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use exceptions. Somehow like this:

```
class twCrawlerCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{

    public function test(){
        $some.... // error happnes!!
            throw new Exception('', 1);//errorcode '1';
    }

    public function excute(){
        $returncode = 0;
        try {
            $this->test();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $returncode = $e->getCode();
        }
        if ($returncode){return $returncode;}

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
<?php

class twCrawlerCommand
{

    private $returncode = 0;
    public function test(){
            $this->returncode = 1;
    }

    public function execute(){
        $this->test();
        if (isset($this->returncode)){return $this->returncode;}
        return "";

    }

}

$foo = new twCrawlerCommand();
print $foo->execute() . "\n";
?>
```